Is there an extension of the recursion theorem
I have seen that the theorem of recursion allows you to derive a recursive function from functions whose domain is larger than or equal to their codomain. I intuitively reached a mathematical formulation where the codomain is necessarily larger than the domain, as follows:
For every set $B$, for every subset $A \subset B$, for every function $f : A \to B$, and for every element $a \in A$:
$1$) There exists a unique function $F : \mathbb{N} \to A$ such that $F(0) = a$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $F(n+1) = f(F(n))$.
Or
$2$) There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a unique function$F : \{0, 1, \ldots, n\} \to A \cup \{F(n)\}$ such that $F(n) \in B$, $F(n) \notin A$, $F(0)=a$ and for all $k < n$, $F(k+1) = f(F(k))$.
I tried to prove it but couldn't. Is it correct, and if so, could you please provide a proof for it

@NaïmFavier I have distinguished two cases: the first case is when  $A$  is not left; in this case, the recursive function formed will be similar to the one in the recursion theorem. The second case is when the set $A$ is left, where a recursive function is formed with a finite domain and its maximum limit value $n$ and The image of this  $n$  in this function will be the first value outside $A$.

Where is F taking values in your second case? Also, how does the first case work if f(F(0)) lands outside of A?

@RodrigoNicolauAlmeida if $f(F(0)) \notin A$ then the second case applies with $n = 1$.

@RodrigoNicolauAlmeida It's just as Naïm Favier told you, because when one of the two cases is met, it necessarily means the other is not.

One way to prove this would be to extend $f$ to a function $f^\star : A + 1 \to A + 1$ (where $A + 1$ is the disjoint union of $A$ with a singleton set, say $\{\star\}$) as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
f^\star(a) &= f(a)\text{ if $f(a) \in A$} \\
f^\star(a) &= \star\text{ otherwise} \\
f^\star(\star) &= \star
\end{align}
$$
The recursion theorem then gives you a function $F : \mathbb{N} \to A + 1$ and you can then consider whether the set $F^{-1}(\star)$ is empty to get your two cases.
(As a variant, you could also have $f^\star : B + 1 \to B + 1$.)

Thank you very much for your good answer. Regarding the last line, I didn't understand the idea you suggest following to reach the solution. Could you please clarify it further?

Send $a \in A$ to $f(a)$, $b \in B \setminus A$ and $\star$ to $\star$.

Good idea  , thanks sir
